# Why am I unable to resize my GLWindow (resizing cursor doesn't even show up)?

Tags: java, jogl

I'm trying to learn OpenGL off a tutorial that uses JOGL to make a 2D game.
My code is pretty much identical aside from a few name changes and better formatting but for some reason, unlike the person's from the tutorial, my window is not resizable.

```
// Main window class
public class Display
{
    private static GLWindow window = null;
    private static FPSAnimator fps;

    public Display()
    {
        GLProfile.initSingleton();
        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        GLCapabilities glc = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        window = GLWindow.create(glc);
        window.setSize(640, 320);
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.addGLEventListener(new GraphicListener());
        fps = new FPSAnimator(window, 60);
        fps.start();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It'll maximise and shrink just fine and I can drag it around, but even though I set it to be resizable, it's just not. The little resizing arrows that appear when touching the sides of any other window never even show up.

Comment: Maybe you're affected by this bug: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1296 Please rather report your JOGL specific issues on our official forum rather than here because lots of contributors don't come here.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? (Btw. you're using Sam Parker's tutorial series too, aren't you?)

Answer (score 0):

It should be resizable even though the resizing arrows don't show up. You just have to click very close to the edge.